# How to do a fast matrix multiplication for each column of two matrices without for loops?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization, multiplication

I have two matrices `A` and `B` for which I want to do a multiplication for each of their columns to produce a new matrix. The first thing cross my mind is

```
A = rand(4,3);
B = rand(4,3);

for J=1:SIZE(A,2)
    for jj=1:size(B,2)
        C(:,:,m) = A(:,j)*B(:,jj)' ;
        m = m+1 ;
    end
end
```

But I don't want to use `for` loops which makes it slow. Is there any way?

I am going to use the matrices of third dimension of `C`, the ones which are built by multiplication of columns of `A` and `B`, Is it better to first build the `C` and then use its 3rd dimension matrices in each loop or just do the multiplication in each loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
N1 = size(A,1);
N2 = size(B,1);
C = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 4 3 2]),permute(B,[4 1 2 3])),N1,N2,[])
```

You could avoid going to the 4th dimension as listed next, but it's still marginally slower than the earlier 4D approach -

```
C = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),B(:).'),N1,N2,[])
```

Comment: @shalooshaloo In response to the edit, you can use the vectorized approach  from this answer and then directly use the matrices of C in its third dimension with `C(:,:,iter)`, where `iter` would be your loop iterator. Thus, with this vectorized approach, you would be pre-calculating C. I am assuming you would be using those C values inside some loop. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah it makes sense, You think is there any difference when you first build the `C` and then use it in iterations ,`C( : , : , iter)` or just multiply the columns in for loop?

Comment: @shalooshaloo I think a lot would depend on how you actually use those `C(:,:,iter)` values. These days JIT is quite powerful, but vaguely understood on how it optimizes for-loops.

Comment: Your solution is written when the first `for` is for A, how can I change it for the case the first `for` is on B's columns?

Comment: @shalooshaloo `reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 4 2 3]),permute(B,[4 1 3 2])),N1,N2,[])`.

Comment: I checked for a larg size data, 1024 by 1024 samples, it was a little slow. Could you modify your second solution for the case that the first `for` loop is on B's columns? would it be faster in relative to the first solution which has a fourth dimension?

Comment: @shalooshaloo I think it will still be slower than the first approach as was with the original case.

Comment: Although this question is for some weeks ago, I hope you could help me, Is there any faster way to compute `C`?

Comment: @shalooshaloo I think if you are looking to vectorize things, this is it. If JIT supported loopy solution performs better, stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682044/2586922), you can generate all 4-fold combinations of row and column indices of the two matrices (with [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)) and then compute the products:

```
[m, p] = size(A);
[n, q] = size(B);
[mm, nn, qq, pp] = ndgrid(1:m, 1:n, 1:q, 1:p);
C = reshape(A(mm+(pp-1)*m).*B(nn+(qq-1)*n), m, n, p*q);
```

Comment: I have checked for a for example `A=rand(50)` and `B=rand(50)` and the previous solution was faster

Comment: @shalooshaloo Yes, `bsxfun` is usually faster than anything else. It would have been my first suggestion, but Divakar arrived first :-)